# Finding non-numeric values in varchar column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

**Requirement :**

Generic query/function to check if the value provided in a varchar column in a table is actually a number & the precision does not exceed the allowed precision.

**Available values:**

Table_Name, Column_Name, Allowed Precision, Allowed Scale

General advise would be to create a function & use to_number() to validate the value however it won't validate the allowed length (precision-scale).

**My solution:**

Validate Number using Regexp `NOT REGEXP_LIKE(COLUMN_NAME, '^-?[0-9.]+$')`

Validate Length of left component (before decimal) (I have no idea what's its actually called) because for scale, oracle automatically rounds off if required. As the actual column is varchar i will use substr, instr to find the component on the left of decimal point.

As above Regexp allows number like 123...123124..55 I will also validate the number of decimal points. [If > 1 then error]

**Query to find invalid number's:**

```
Select * From Table_Name 
Where
(NOT REGEXP_LIKE(COLUMN_NAME, '^-?[0-9.]+$')
OR
Function_To_Fetch_Left_Component(COLUMN_NAME) > (Precision-Scale)
/* Can use regexp_substr now but i already had a function for that */
OR
LENGTH(Column_Name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Column_Name,'.','')) > 1
/* Can use regexp_count aswell*/)
```

---

I was happy & satisfied with my solution until a column with only '.' value escaped my check and I saw the limitation of my checks. Although adding another check to validate this as well will solve my problem the `solution` as a whole looks very inefficient to me.

I will really appreciate a better solution [in any way].

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The precision means that you want at most `allowed_precision` digits in the number (strictly speaking, not counting leading zeros, but I'll ignore that).  The scale means that at most `allowed_scale` can be after the decimal point.

This suggests a regular expression such as:

```
[-]?[0-9]{1,<before>}[.]?[0-9]{0,<after>}
```

You can construct the regular expression:

```
NOT REGEXP_LIKE(COLUMN_NAME,
                REPLACE(REPLACE('[-]?[0-9]{1,<before>}[.]?[0-9]{0,<after>}', '<before>', allowed_precision - allowed_scale
                               ), '<after>', allowed_scale)
```

Now, variable regular expressions are highly inefficient.  You can do the logic using `like` and other functions as well.  I think the conditions are:

```
(column_name not like '%.%.%' and
 column_name not like '_%-%' and
 translate(column_name, '0123456789-.x', 'x') is null and
 length(translate(column_name, '-.x', 'x') <= allowed_precision and
 length(translate(column_name, '-.x', 'x') >= 1 and
 instr(translate(column_name, '-.x', 'x'), '.') <= allowed_precision - allowed_scale
)
```

Comment: Hi, The suggestion REGEXP `[-]?[0-9]{1,<before>}[.]?[0-9]{0,<after>}` does not work as intended 
because if the decimal is missing it accepts a total of `before + after` digits which exceeds the allowed value on the left side of the decimal. 
Eg for number(4,2) the query accepts 1111 which will be rejected by oracle later. I would really appreciate if you explain translate a little bit more because I am not able to understand the like queryyy with translate.

Comment: If the use of this condition `translate(column_name, '0123456789-.x', 'x') is null` is to find if there is any character apart from the one mentioned then the syntax should be `translate(column_name, 'x0123456789-.', 'x') is null` else it will replace 0 with x and show instead of replacing all digits with ''/blank/empty. Please advise.

Comment: Your final hint to drop the regexp made me create the following query which decreases the execution time by more than half in my tests!!! `with x as
  (Select '012341' temp_test from dual) 
    Select * From x
  WHERE (Translate(temp_test,'x0123456789-.','x') is not null
  OR temp_test = '.'
  OR temp_test = '-'
  OR temp_test like '%-%-%'
  OR temp_test like '%.%.%'
  OR Instr(temp_test||'.','.')-1 > 5  )  ;`I hope i covered all the checks required as I am particularly not worried about accepting scientific notations or exceeding precision becoz of decimal component as oracle will tc.

Comment: Updated Query: `with x as
  (Select '012341' temp_test from dual) 
    Select * From x
  WHERE (Translate(temp_test,'x0123456789-.','x') is not null
  OR temp_test = '.'
  OR temp_test = '-'
  OR temp_test = '-.'
  OR Instr(temp_test,'-') > 1
  OR temp_test like '%-%-%'
  OR temp_test like '%.%.%'
  OR Instr(temp_test||'.','.')-1 > 5  )  ;`

Answer (score 2):

Look for:

- One-or-more digits optionally followed by a decimal point and zero-or-more digits; or
- A leading decimal point (no preceding unit digit) and then one or more (decimal) digits.

Like this:

```
Select *
From   Table_Name 
Where  NOT REGEXP_LIKE(COLUMN_NAME, '^[+-]?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)$')
```

If you do not want zero-padded values in the number string then:

```
Select *
From   Table_Name 
Where  NOT REGEXP_LIKE(COLUMN_NAME, '^[+-]?(([1-9]\d*|0)(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)$')
```

With precision and scale (assuming it works as per a `NUMBER( precision, scale )` data type and `scale < precision`):

```
Select *
From   Table_Name 
Where  NOT REGEXP_LIKE(COLUMN_NAME, '^[+-]?(\d{1,'||(precision-scale)||'}(\.\d{0,'||scale||'})?|\.\d{1,'||scale||'})$')
```

or, for non-zero-padded numbers with precision and scale:

```
Select *
From   Table_Name 
Where  NOT REGEXP_LIKE(COLUMN_NAME, '^[+-]?(([1-9]\d{0,'||(precision-scale-1)||'}|0)(\.\d{0,'||scale||'})?|\.\d{1,'||scale||'})$')
```

or, for any precision and scale:

```
Select *
From   Table_Name 
Where  NOT REGEXP_LIKE(
             COLUMN_NAME,
             CASE
               WHEN scale <= 0
               THEN '^[+-]?(\d{1,'||precision||'}0{'||(-scale)||'})$'
               WHEN scale < precision
               THEN '^[+-]?(\d{1,'||(precision-scale)||'}(\.\d{0,'||scale||'})?|\.\d{1,'||scale||'})$'
               WHEN scale >= precision
               THEN '^[+-]?(0(\.0{0,'||scale||'})?|0?\.0{'||(scale-precision)||'}\d{1,'||precision||'})$'
             END
           )
```

Comment: Just for my understanding ^ - Begining... [+-]? - 0 or 1 occurrence of either + or -... ([1-9]\d*|0) - starting with 1-9 followed by 0 or 1 occurrence of digits or a zero so that 1 zero is allowed however multiple are not..... (\.\d*)? - 0 or 1 occurrence of 1 decimal + digits.... OR.... decimal followed by 1 or more digits... $ - End.... Thank you for your time.

Comment: @pOrinG `[1-9]\d*` is starting with the digit 1-9 then followed by zero-or-more of any digit (0-9) so `([1-9]\d*|0)` is either the `[1-9]\d*` pattern or a single `0` so that the integer part can be any number of digits but must start with a non-zero digit unless it is the single digit `0`. The bit about decimals - yes.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you please clarify how this works with the variable precision and scale that the OP wanted?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak Updated

Comment: Very nice.  However, it gives a false positive for `3.391E2`, when using NUMBER(5,2).  Your logic says it isn't valid.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak The OP did not ask about scientific notation.

Comment: It's true, but since answers on SO are better if they're generally useful, I thought it should be mentioned.  Also, along those lines, the assumption that scale < precision is not necessarily true.  Some readers might not realize that.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak (Untested but) I think I've covered all the (valid) cases for precision and scale in the latest update.

Comment: @MT0 Thanks for the extended version. For my understanding & clarification on Assuming (Precision:7, Scale:2) `'^[+-]?(\d{1,5}(\.\d{0,2})?|\.\d{1,2})$'`
...`^[+-]?` : Beginning zero or one occurrence of plus or minus.
...Followed by...`\d{1,5}` : zero to five digits
...Followed by...`(\.\d{0,2})?` : zero or one occurrence of [decimal and then zero to two digits]
...OR...`\.\d{1,2}` : [decimal and then one to two digits].

I don't understand the importance of the last [OR] for the decimal component because the first condition should cover everything i guess?

Comment: @pOrinG `\d{1,5}` is 1 to 5 digits. The last [or] covers the case when someone write `.12` (without a leading zero) which is a case the first part doesn't cover.

Comment: @MT0 Got it. Thanks!!