# Efficient query to find invalid number's in varchar column

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have already asked almost the same question before:
[Finding non-numeric values in varchar column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47711667/finding-non-numeric-values-in-varchar-column/47712294?noredirect=1#comment82430532_47712294)

And I received some great answer's and idea's to make not only fix the issue in my query but also make it much more efficient.

**Old Query:**

```
Select * From Table_Name 
Where
(NOT REGEXP_LIKE(COLUMN_NAME, '^-?[0-9.]+$')
OR
LENGTH(Function_To_Fetch_Left_Component(COLUMN_NAME)) > (Precision-Scale)
OR
LENGTH(Column_Name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Column_Name,'.','')) > 1)
```

**New Query:**

```
Select * From Table_Name
WHERE (Translate(column_name,'x0123456789-.','x') is not null
OR column_name = '.'
OR column_name = '-'
OR column_name = '-.'
OR Instr(column_name,'-') > 1
OR column_name like '%-%-%'
OR column_name like '%.%.%'
OR Instr(column_name||'.','.')-1 > (precision-scale)  )  ;
```

**Known limitations which are okay:**

1.) Doesn't handle scientific notation. Its by design as I want to reject those.

2.) Doesn't check total precision (decimal component) however as while inserting oracle itself round's it off I am fine with it.

3.) Doesn't check for leading zero's.

Please help to see if the above query cover's everything and I haven't missing anything.

---

Another great solution by one Stackoverflow member however increased execution time by 2.5 times:

**Function:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function temp_is_number(p_test_value varchar2,
                                     p_scale NUMBER,
                                     p_precision NUMBER) return varchar2  is

  l_result varchar2(1);
begin
  execute immediate 'DECLARE l_number NUMBER; ' ||
                    'l_test_number NUMBER(' || p_precision || ',' || p_scale || '); ' ||
                    'BEGIN ' ||
                    '  l_number := cast(:b1 as number); ' ||
                    '  l_test_number := cast(:b1 as number); ' ||
                    '  IF (l_number = l_test_number) THEN ' ||
                    '    :b2 := ''Y''; ' ||
                    '  ELSE ' ||
                    '    :b2 := ''N''; ' ||
                    '  END IF; ' ||
                    'EXCEPTION ' ||
                    '  WHEN OTHERS THEN ' ||
                    '    :b2 := ''N''; ' ||
                    'END;'
        using in p_test_value, out l_result;
  return l_result;
end;
/

Select Count(1) from Table_Name Where temp_is_number (Column_Name,scale,precision) = 'N';
```

Comment: Since the function must be generic, then your solution does not support different setting of NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTER, NLS_ISO_CURRENCY, NLS_CURRENCY, NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY. Also a scientific notation is not supportled (like `10E+34`, `-12e-10`).

Comment: @krokodilko  Thank you for your response & Yes, it doesn't support NLS parameter changes and i should look into it in future however my `Generic` currently only extends till it must work for different tables/columns in the same DB with number datatype. Also I am not really concerned about the scientific notations. I think then the best way to move forward would be with a function with to_number() as it will cover all this but that would increase the execution time by 2.5 times and we use this check a lot (LOT!).

Comment: If you're using Oracle 12c R2 you should use the new built-in function, [VALIDATE_CONVERSION](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.htm#SQLRF-GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD)

Comment: @APC Interesting function however I am on Oracle 11g.

Comment: One question about what exactly is a requirement - do you want to have **a function** that as quickly as possible checks whether the value is a number? Or do you want to have **a query** that as quickly as possible pick rows which don't contain numbers (or do contain numbers) from the table ? Both requirements are similar, but not the same, the latter can be achieved using a slower function, in turn the most fastest function doesn't guarantee that the query will be the fastest.

Comment: @krokodilko The requirement is that I need a query that counts all invalid number's in a given table,column(varchar type) before inserting in another table, column (number datatype). That is why I pass the precision,scale of the target table, column to validate. So if the query return's 0 I proceed with the insertion else fail the process and exit. In my previous comment about `a function with to_number()` I meant to create a function which i will use in the query where condition to count invalid values.

Comment: So the query on the table will be executed **only once**, not many times (in the second case you could do the check only once in the trigger and write the value to an additional column in the table for which the index would be created). If the majority numbers in the table are correct, use the idea from this thread - [Ask Tom -  Validation of a number within a VARCHAR2 field](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2460648511591) ==> `and decode( replace(translate(tmpvalue,'1234567890.','00000000000'),'0',''), NULL, my_to_number(tmpvalue), 0 ) = 0;`

Comment: @krokodilko I don't have control over source data & as I am doing this check on-fly while accepting source data for any of my (almost 60 tables with at-least if not more 120 number datatype columns) I want to reject & throw error in-case the number isn't valid for that particular field.Secondly the function shown in the thread will not help me because it's not validating the precision,scale at any level. Let me edit & add another proposed solution in the question by one of our SO member's which was great and solved all my problem but increased the execution time by almost 2.5 times.